# I changed a page in /_layouts/, now how do I get SharePoint to reload it?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have a Page Viewer webpart that displays `/_layouts/google.htm` and needs changing. I applied the changes to the file google.html in `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\12\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\` on the web server.

After countless page refreshes and webpart reloads, how do I get SharePoint to display the new version of the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recycling the Application Pool in IIS should do the trick

[image: Recycle App Pool]

Comment: Is there anything I need to be aware of before doing this on a production site? I recycle app pools on other asp.net sites all the time but they're much simpler than SharePoint. Will sessions be dropped? Will any workflows be affected?

Comment: Yes, session state will be dropped with a recycle (unless you're using a StateServer or SqlSessionState instead of the default InProc)

Comment: Note that SharePoint itself does not use session state, MOSS 2007 configures SQL session state. So unless you personally configured SharePoint to use in-memeory session state recycling App Pools should not be a problem. App Pool recycling would be done by SharePoint itslef if you used solution deployment infrastructure to apply your changes.